# Using background images formatter for taxonomy in views

Tags: views, media

I have an image field per taxonomy vocabulary that I want to set as background to each views-row. I have the view filtered by taxonomy term, and I have set the taxonomy_image field as background.

However, I don't know which CSS selector would be appropriate. The tokens available are c.date, c.page, c.user, random, site info, and users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not disabled **Add default classes** under **Style Settings** of image field then you can use views_field_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME class to play with css.

For example If you have a field with machine name **field_book_category_icon** then after adding this field to your view you can get a class **views-field-field-book-category-icon** on front end when ever you render that view on your page.